# PYTHON | Inheriting Attributes from Main Class In Nested Subclass

Tags: python, class, subclass

I've been trying to inherit properties from a main class into a nested subclass without passing it as a parameter when initialized. Is there a way to do this?

```py
class main:
  def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg = arg
  
  class sub(main):
    def __init__(self):
      self.arg = main.arg
```

Is there a proper way to do this? And are nested classes a bad practice?

Comment: You can't do that because the name `main` isn't defined until after the main class definition is finished.

Comment: Nested classes are a thing, but not frequently used, but I'm not sure why the nested class would need to be a subclass of the outer class.

Comment: Right.  USUALLY (overgeneralizing), a nested class is something you don't want visible to the outside.  In that case, having a derived class doesn't make sense.

Comment: I need nested class to receive information from the main class. I'm running a loop on the main class with information that needs to be passed to the subclass but I don't want to run it on the subclass since the subclass only outputs information when initialized

Comment: You don't need a class inside a class to achieve this.  What you need is a method (function) in the class. So whilst you could do this, it would be considered poor practice.